# Is it possible to install Ubuntu in my usb and save whatever file i want in my hard drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu in a usb. But after installing Ubunte, if for example i want to download an mp3 file or anything else, is it possible to use my pc's hard drive to save it there. I just want to have Ubuntu in my usb, anything else i want to be stored to my hard drive, is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I assume that Windows is installed in an internal drive. In this case you can create a separate partition with the NTFS file system on the internal drive, a **data** partition. Boot into Windows, shrink the Windows partition to create unallocated drive space. Reboot and boot into Ubuntu. Use `gparted` to create a partition and the NTFS file system and add the label `data` (or another name that you like better). It is also a good idea to remove Windows fast startup. Otherwise Windows is semi-hibernating and the NTFS file system may be read-only or not available for Ubuntu.

Comment: You can even create an ext4 casper-rw partition on your internal HDD, and the USB drive will use it for persistence when it is plugged into that computer. Casper-rw Persistent partitions only work with the same version of the same OS though.